# How does eval(value) in asp.Net work

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can you people explain me how this eval() works..

'<%# Eval("Value") %>'

i'm unable to understand how does it bind the data ..
For example in this article how does it get path the path file?

*http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Download-Files-from-GridView-using-LinkButton-Click-Event-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx*

Comment: The important code there is in the codebehind: `GridView1.DataSource = files; GridView1.DataBind();` Once bound, you can use `Eval()` to get each value from your set of data.

Comment: "files" here contains filename and filepath rite ? im confused on how CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' is getting only the file path .. ?

Answer (score 1):

Review following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx

```
public static Object Eval(
    Object container,
    string expression
)
```